# flutter access store mobx from other screen

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, mobx

how to accessing the MobX stores across the screen like inject store in react?

```dart
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> { 
  final _store = exStore();
  void init() {
   _store.setTitle('foo');
  }
}
```

when navigate to home screen, i need to get data title

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}



class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> { 
  final _store = exStore();
  void init() {
   print(_store.title); // return null
  }
}
```

i need the _store.title return 'foo'..

Comment: Are you successful in doing this? I have this problem too

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you just need to create your instance outside of any widget so that be global, like following..

1. screen A

```dart
store = exStore();

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> { 
  void init() {
   store.setTitle('foo');
  }
}
```

2. screen B

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}



class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> { 
  void init() {
   print(store.title); // return null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, what if these widgets are in two different files like screen_a.dart and screen_b.dart? How we will access store in the second widget?